# Solution to 5 equations in 5 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have the following 5 equations in 5 variables(A, B, C, D, E):

1. $2 \times E \times A + D = 1    $
2. $2\times E\times B + D = 0    $
3. $D + E = 2$
4. $A + B + C = 1$
5. $A^2   + B^2 + C = \frac 7 4$

I know the solution is: $ (0 , \frac {-1} 2 , \frac 3 2 ,  1, 1) $. Just don't know how to get there.

Comment: The system represents the intersection of three hyperquadrics and two planes. You can expect eight solutions, I guess, unless there is some kind of degeneracy.

Comment: there is another real solution $$\left(1, \frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{2}, 3, -1\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align} 
2e a+d&=1
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
2 e b+d&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
d+e&=2
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
a+b+c&=1
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
a^2+b^2+c&=\tfrac74
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Substitution of $e=2-d$ from \eqref{3} into \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}
leads to expression of $a$ and $b$ in terms of $d$:

\begin{align}
a &= \tfrac12\frac{d-1}{d-2}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
b &= \tfrac12\frac{d}{d-2}
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

Then,
substitution of these expressions for $a,b$
into \eqref{4}
gives the expression of $c$ in terms of $d$:

\begin{align}
c&=-\tfrac32\frac1{d-2}
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

substitution expressions for $a,b,c$ in terms of $d$ into \eqref{5}
after simple rearrangements,
results in equation is $d$:

\begin{align}
-\tfrac54\frac{(d-1)(d-3)}{(d-2)^2}
&=0
,
\end{align}

so there are two solutions for $d$, $1$ and $3$,
consequently, there are two solutions of \eqref{1}-\eqref{5}:

\begin{align}
a &= 0
,\quad
b = -\tfrac12
,\quad
c = \tfrac32
,\quad
d=1
,\quad 
e=1
,\\
\text{and}\quad
a &= 1
,\quad
b = \tfrac32
,\quad
c = -\tfrac32
,\quad 
d=3
,\quad
e = -1
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

From the first two, $E\ne0$. After elimination* of $A, B, C, D$, you get

$$ \frac{E-1}{2E} \left( \frac{E-1}{2E} -1\right)+\frac{E-2}{2E} \left(\frac{E-2}{2E} -1\right)=\frac34.$$

or simply

$$E^2=1.$$

The rest follows.

---

*Use $D=2-E$, express $A, B$ in terms of $E$ and plug them in the difference of the last two.